# Tomcat serves not found but website works

Tags: java, tomcat8, jsf-2.2

The website is up and look fine, but when I do inspect using google chrome I see in console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

and my home page is very simple that not import any css or js file[image]

And that's why when I check the status of my website in production for example in this website: https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/

I get 404 error and my website is really working.

Comment: Is there a question here? Some resource is trying to load and a 404 comes back. Check the network tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you DONT put your welcome page (index.html...) page under webapp folder, try to put your welcome page (index.html, index.xhtml...) under webapp folder directly
scr>main>webapp>index.xhtml
and also configure web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
```